# attaching files in base64 to mailgun.js inside node.js

Tags: node.js, base64, attachment, mailgun

I am using the official [mailgun.js](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun.js), and i fond it very confusing to see how can i add attachments in base64 encoding. The docs over there are with the old mailgun-js. and some parts are linking to 404 pages.

I am using it inside node.js. Can anyone tell me how can i add said attachments, in link i gave above?

This is what i have now:

```
const formData = require('form-data');
const Mailgun = require('mailgun.js');
const mg = new Mailgun(formData);
const mailgunClient = mg.client({username: 'api', key: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY});

mailgunClient.messages.create(process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN, {
    from: process.env.MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS,
    to: [message.recipients],
    subject: message.subject,
    text: "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!",
    html: "<h1>Testing some Mailgun awesomness!</h1>",
    attachment:[
        {
            name: 'attachment.jpg',
            encoding: "multipart/form-data",
            content: "Base64 string"
        }
      ]
  })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is dealing with this:
I have found the solution.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const contents = fs.readFileSync('path/To/File', {encoding: 'base64'});

const buffer = Buffer.from(contents, 'base64');
```

Then, add it like this to the message:

```
mailgunClient.messages.create(process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN, {
    from: process.env.MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS,
    to: [message.recipients],
    subject: message.subject,
    text: "test email",
    html: "<h1>test email</h1>",
    attachment: [{filename: 'myfile.jpg', data: buffer}]
  })
  .then(msg => console.log(msg)) // logs response data
  .catch(err => console.log(err)); // logs any error
}
```